# In AS3, load a text file into a string

Tags: actionscript-3, asynchronous

I've been trying to load a text file into a string variable. The text file named `text.txt` containing `successful`. Here's the code:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var text:String = "text";
    private var textLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    public function Main() {
        textLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
        function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
            trace("Before 1: " + text); //output: text
            trace("Before 2: " + e.target.data); //output: successful
            text = e.target.data;
            trace("After 1: " + text); //output: successful - yay!!! it worked

        }

        textLoader.load(new URLRequest("text.txt"));

        trace("After 2: " + text); //output: text - what??? nothing happened??? but it just worked

    }

}
```

**Output:**

`After 2: text
 Before 1: text
 Before 2: successful
 After 1: successful`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing a synchronous vs asynchronous problem

The function `onLoaded` is called asynchronously by `textLoader` when `Event.COMPLETE` is dispatched, as opposed to `"After 2"` which is called directly after `textLoader.load`.

What you must keep in mind is `textLoader.load` is non-blocking which means `"After 2"` is probably (you can assume always) executed before `onLoaded`.

If at this point of the answer you're still confused, I'd say that loading a file takes time and executing an instruction may vary in time but is mostly infinitely shorter than it takes to load a file (imagine this file is 4go large). You cannot predict what will happen, maybe the disk is already very busy you may need to wait! But you could use this precious time to do something else totally independant from the text file, and that is why it is sometimes made asynchronously by programming languages (`php` for example loads a file synchronously).

**Next step**

---

Now that I have explained that `"After 2"` does not really exist, you have to use `"After 1"`
as an entry point but nothing helps you from making a function named `afterLoad` which you would call like this

```
public function Main() {
        textLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

        function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
            trace("Before 1: " + text); //output: text
            trace("Before 2: " + e.target.data); //output: successful
            text = e.target.data;
            afterLoad();
        }

        textLoader.load(new URLRequest("text.txt"));
    }


}

private function afterLoad():void {
    trace("After: " + text); // it should work now :)
}
```

Comment: So what should I do then?

Comment: But can and how I get it (the loaded text) later on?

Comment: The point is that you have to go through `afterLoad` or directly inside  `onLoaded`. The only alternative is to use a custom event to dispatch when main is ready, but this is redundant. You could rename `afterLoad` to `MainWithDataLoaded` if it helps you understand what the core of this problem is.

Comment: OK. I got it. So now I write the rest of the code into `afterLoad()` - `MainWithDataLoaded()` instead of `Main()`